# hide and show li at specific time interval

Tags: jquery

I have a html with 6 sections. The first and second section will be always displayed. Sections from 3 to 6 will have to be displayed one after the other. Means Third section will be displayed in the page for 3 seconds and later it should fade and fourth section will be displayed for 3 seconds and like this it should do till the sixth section. In my fiddle, third, fourth , fifth and sixth are always displayed..I want third to be displayed for 3 seconds, then it should disapper and fourth should appear and then fifth and so on. So I need to hide and show these li after 3 seconds and it should not stop even if it hits the last li. It should keep on going
Can somebody please help me in this?
I have created a sample fiddle for this with the html structure
http://jsfiddle.net/Ha4CS/5/

**CODE**

```
<li>
    <h4>1. First section.</h4>
    <div>
        <p>Contents for the first li.Contents for the first li.Contents for the first li.Contents for the first li.</p>
        <a href="#" >Go</a>     
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: yes..I tried something like this.. but this is not what I need..http://jsfiddle.net/Ha4CS/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
<div class="product_box">
<ul id="products">
    <li>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <a id="button" href="#" target="_blank">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
       <a id="button" href = "#" target="_blank">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <a id="button" href = "#" target="_blank">Info</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
         var firstLi = $('#products li').first().detach();
        $('#products').append($(firstLi));
     }, 500);

});
```

Css :

```
li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    display: none;
    width: 60px;
}

li:first-child {
display: block;            
}

h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9KgTg/)

Comment: Hi Sankar..Thanks for the reply..I dont want to change the first 2 li's..The first and second li should remain constant..Only form third it should change..Can u please check my updated fiddle..In that I need to display those only one at a time..means first and second wil be there always..Then third should be displayed for 3 seconds..after that fourth should be displayed and so on..can u help me..http://jsfiddle.net/Ha4CS/5/

Answer (score 0):

We achieve by many ways .Here I tried by `setInterval()`

Try this code :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/e39JK/7/)

**JS**:

```
     var i=1;  
     var set= setInterval(function() {
          if(i<5)
           {
             $("#list").html($("#list"+i).clone().fadeIn());

            }
          else
          {
              i=1;
               $("#list").html($("#list"+i).clone().fadeIn());

          }
       i++;
       },3000);
     set();
```

Comment: Hi Manoj..Thanks for the reply..When the fourth section is displayed, the third should be hidden and the fourth needs to be displayed in that place. Similarly, when fifth is displayed, fourth should be hidden..like this it should happen till sixth and then again it has to be repeated..means third section needs to be displayed and 4, 5, 6 hidden like that

Comment: @Manoj..thanks for this updated fiddle..i checked it..the third one fades and the fourth one should appear on the same place where 3 li was. Now the fourth li is showing in the next li. I want all the li's to be shown in the same third li place itself..Also it should not stop at after the sixth li. Once it reaches, sixth, it should again start from third..Hope u understood my requirement..

Comment: Hi Manoj..that is almost what I am looking for..But the li's should be shown only at the third li place. the third one fades and the fourth one should appear on the same place where 3 li was. Now the fourth li is showing in the next li. I want all the li's to be shown in the same third li place itself. Any help on this?

Comment: Also once after the 6th li is shown, 3rd li is not shown with continuity..its like it resets and then starts from the start..its not happening continuosly..Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43903/discussion-between-manoj-and-user1049057)